# Why am i getting "Payer Address Status: unconfirmed" on Paypal payment?

Tags: paypal, payment

on each payment done with Paypal on Magento 1.8.0. i am getting `Payer Address Status: unconfirmed` on the Order details.

I think this is the main reason why i'm getting the *Suspected Fraud* status on each order too.

Any hint on why this is happening and why am i getting that the address status is unconfirmed? Thanks.

***Edit:*** here is a transaction taken from the payment_paypal_standard.log i have just edited some values and changed it with * * *variable_name* * * for privacy reasons. If the variable has the same name in [request] and [ipn] means that their value is the same..for example * * *magento_payer_email* * * and * * *paypal_payer_email* * * are different.

```
2014-09-26T12:53:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => Array
        (
            [business] => ****
            [invoice] => 200000025
            [currency_code] => EUR
            [paymentaction] => sale
            [return] => https://5.144.161.214/it/paypal/standard/success/
            [cancel_return] => https://5.144.161.214/it/paypal/standard/cancel/
            [notify_url] => http://5.144.161.214/it/paypal/ipn/
            [bn] => Varien_Cart_WPS_US
            [item_name] => Artiglass
            [lc] => it_IT
            [charset] => utf-8
            [amount] => 1.00
            [tax] => 0.22
            [shipping] => 0.00
            [discount_amount] => 0.00
            [cmd] => _ext-enter
            [redirect_cmd] => _xclick
            [city] => ***city***
            [country] => IT
            [email] => ***magento_payer_email***
            [first_name] => yari
            [last_name] => ***surname***
            [zip] => 35036
            [state] => PD
            [address1] => ***address***
            [address2] => 
            [address_override] => 1
        )

    [__pid] => 8869
)

2014-09-26T12:54:13+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [ipn] => Array
        (
            [address_city] => ***city***
            [address_country] => Italy
            [address_country_code] => IT
            [address_name] => yari ***surname***
            [address_state] => PD
            [address_status] => unconfirmed
            [address_street] => ***address***
            [address_zip] => 35036
            [business] => ***payment_reciever_email***
            [charset] => windows-1252
            [custom] => 
            [first_name] => Alessandro
            [handling_amount] => 0.00
            [invoice] => 200000025
            [ipn_track_id] => abeeab0b3ee4f
            [item_name] => Artiglass
            [item_number] => 
            [last_name] => ***paypal_payer_surname***
            [mc_currency] => EUR
            [mc_fee] => 0.39
            [mc_gross] => 1.22
            [notify_version] => 3.8
            [payer_email] => ***paypal_payer_email***
            [payer_id] => BUJ7BXSXRQ7PU
            [payer_status] => verified
            [payment_date] => 05:53:41 Sep 26, 2014 PDT
            [payment_fee] => 
            [payment_gross] => 
            [payment_status] => Completed
            [payment_type] => instant
            [protection_eligibility] => Eligible
            [quantity] => 1
            [receiver_email] => ***payment_reciever_email***
            [receiver_id] => C7TREZME4WYUA
            [residence_country] => IT
            [shipping] => 0.00
            [tax] => 0.00
            [transaction_subject] => 
            [txn_id] => 78772277D7485002W
            [txn_type] => web_accept
            [verify_sign] => APioMws2wuxbSdpVCGS5l5doAkp1AWHOvHSThPaCCSoI0oDj9cp0j..H
        )

    [postback_to] => https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
    [__pid] => 8872
)
```

Answer (score 1):

for magento 1.9.0.1 comment in: `public function registerCaptureNotification($amount, $skipFraudDetection = false)`, code line:

```
} else {
           // if (!$skipFraudDetection || !$isSameCurrency) {
            //    $this->setIsFraudDetected(true);
           //  }
            $this->_updateTotals(array('base_amount_paid_online' => $amount));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

PayPal documentation states: `An address is confirmed if the buyer’s credit card billing address matches his or her shipping address. In some instances, PayPal can also confirm an address by examining the buyer’s PayPal account history.`

There are additional ways to get "confirmed" address, see details [Shipping to a Buyer’s Confirmed Address article](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/gen/shipping-address-outside) on PayPal site

Comment: Ok thanks Andrii and do you think this could lead Magento to set a `Suspected Fraud` status to an order?

Comment: Can you add a .log of the PayPal Standard by enabling Debug Mode = Yes via PayPal configuration? Also in the Magento 1.9 (see http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/new-features-ce19-ee114#ee114-11400-checkout) PayPal Express Checkout can be configured to work exactly in the same way as PayPal Standard. Express do not rely on IPN thus works much more smoothly with order management; additionally you can perform capture/refund from Magemto. With Standard you can not take advantage of it, see https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_additional-payment-ref-impl1

Comment: I have edited the above post with a transaction taken from the paypal debug log. Unfortunately i cannot update Magento to 1.9 and now i am running on 1.8

Hope this helps, thanks

Comment: Most likely issue is here:
public function registerCaptureNotification($amount, $skipFraudDetection = false)
Were fraud status is set. Change:

**if (!$skipFraudDetection) {
                    $this->setIsFraudDetected(true);**
to

**if ($skipFraudDetection) {
                    $this->setIsFraudDetected(true);**

This is a slight hack but i can not see any issues with the .log you provided and to say more i'll need to debug :) If it will suits you i'll update my answer.

Comment: Hello Andrii thanks for your answer. Yes i did that hack a while ago and it removes the "Supected Fraud" status but it's somehow avoiding the problem rather than solving it... anyway, i think i will stick to this for the moment!